# Exception while building a war file via (maven install) for a spring boot project with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-mongodb, spring-bean

I am trying to build a `spring-boot` application with `mongodb`. I excluded the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency and using `mongodb-driver` 3.12.5.

My application.properties file contains only `spring.data.mongodb.uri=connection _string`.

With this above configuration I am unable to build a war file to deploy in server. It is giving the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: Why do you exclude `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` ? You need both of them

Comment: i excluded because i am not using mongoRepository in Spring Boot instead i am writing my own methods to make necessary actions.
but i am a beginner i might miss certain points, please tell me why do we need to have two dependencies ?

Comment: You need both of them because it's how Spring integrates wth MongoDB. With Spring-mongoDB you have `CrudRepository`, `MongoTemplate`, etc... It would be helpful if you share your `pom.xml` to check how did you exclude it.

Comment: i added mongodb java driver. as i said i am not using the CrudRepository and any such Classes in spring-data-mongodb. so i excluded it

Comment: It's part of Spring-MongoDB driver, you can't exclude it.

Comment: while we add the dependencies at the start of creating a spring-boot project. i did not chose spring mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue was solved by replacing the mongodb-driver dependency with mongodb-java-driver dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

as for the situation i faced i did not add a dependency that i am using in the application. that was the mistake.